# Category page in Jekyll works for one category but not another

Tags: jekyll, categories, github-pages

My Jekyll site, hosted on github.io, has a category page that generates correctly for one category, but not another.

GitHub source: https://github.com/drovani/drovani.github.io
Website: http://rovani.net

The two category pages are nearly identical.
This one works (http://rovani.net/category/exactly-one-hobby/), located in `/category/exactly-one-hobby.md`.

```
---
layout: category
title: "Exactly One Hobby"
category: "Exactly One Hobby"
---
```

But this one does not work (http://rovani.net/category/rovani-in-c-sharp), located in `/category/rovani-in-c-sharp.md`.

```
---
layout: category
title: "Rovani in C&sharp;"
category: "Rovani in C&sharp;"
---
```

Thinking the HTML entity might have been the issue, I tried removing it from the category entirely (making everything `rovani-in-c`), to no avail. Any suggestions for what may be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

As with so many other problems (which I completely overlooked before posting this) of developing on a Windows platform - the files defaulted to saving with an encoding of `Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252`, when it needed to explicitly set the encoding to be `Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001`

To someone else who may be on a Windows platform **check the file encoding** before you drive yourself mad with debugging.